# Functional Mock-up Unit no valid when implemented in Python (created in OpenModelica)

Tags: python, modelica, openmodelica, fmi, pyfmi

I having trouble here when implementing a Modelica code as a FMU in Python. This is de model:

```
model integrator
  Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.Integrator y_to_x[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {2, -12}, extent = {{20, 20}, {-20, -20}}, rotation = -180)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealOutput x[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {88, -12}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {100, 10}, extent = {{-10, -10}, {10, 10}}, rotation = 0)));
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput y[6] annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-82, -12}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0), iconTransformation(origin = {-80, -40}, extent = {{-20, -20}, {20, 20}}, rotation = 0)));
equation
  connect(y_to_x.y, x) annotation(
    Line(points = {{24, -12}, {88, -12}}, color = {0, 0, 127}, thickness = 0.5));
  connect(y, y_to_x.u) annotation(
    Line(points = {{-82, -12}, {-22, -12}}, color = {0, 0, 127}, thickness = 0.5));

annotation(
    uses(Modelica(version = "4.0.0")));
end integrator;
```

Then I've created the FMU and wrote the same code as always in Python:

```
fmu_file = 'integrator.fmu'
model_description = fmpy.read_model_description(fmu_file)
dump(fmu_file)

t_start = 0; t_end = 200; t_step = 0.01

outputs = fmpy.simulate_fmu(
    fmu_file,
    start_time = t_start,
    stop_time = t_end,
    output_interval = t_step,
    input=np.array([0,2000,0,0,0,0], dtype=[("y[1]",np.float64), ("y[2]",np.float64), 
                                             ("y[3]",np.float64), ("y[4]",np.float64)
                                             ("y[5]",np.float64), ("y[6]",np.float64)]),
    output = ('x[1]','x[2]','x[3]','x[4]','x[5]','x[6]'))
```

The results are different in both interfaces (OpenModelica and Python). I have tried in serveral ways but it dosen't work. Anyone has a clue on what's going on?

Comment: In OpenModelica FMU made as "model exchange" is sometimes better.  Go to Tools/Options/FMI and click for Model Exchange. Below that choose Native. Solver I usually use CVODE

Comment: It still dosen't work :( I get output 0 in all variables. I have curiosity on why do you use CVODE,  is it better than the default solver? Thank you so much, Janpeter!

Comment: I have compiled your code in OpenModelica and exported an FMU and run it in Python using the alternative PyFMI. Then I set y[2] = 1 and we get x[2] increase with time while the others components of x remains zero. I think the problem has something to do with how you handle input.   I have given initial values simply, while when you use "input" you should supply a time-series.   The only reason I use PyFMI is because I am more used to it. My experience with FMPy is good however and give usually the same results.   Can you explain in words what you want your input to be?

Comment: And change integration routine to CVODE has no impact here. So keep what you have.

Comment: And if you like to provide initial values to the FMPy function simulate.fmpy () you use the field start_vaues and supply a dictionary with the values you want. Default is zero. Thus, to reproduce what I did you should have: start_values = {'y[2]' : 1.0}, I think.

Comment: Hi! The solution was setting `start_values={}` instead of `inputs=[]` as you suggested. Thank you very much!!!!!! 

Comment: Good. Consider to click on the arrow up if you find comments, answers useful. That is how we (also) thank each other here.

Comment: You've got it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sum-up of my earlier comments  and I just noted that you supplied and answer yourself.

I am not sure I understand exactly what you want to do, but here is what I understand.
See it as a partial answer.  Perhaps someone else with more FMPy knowledge can add on.

Your Modelica code works well in OpenModelica 1.21 and I exported an FMU of ME type
for use in Linux Python environment.

**A bit tricky** is that you in your Modelica model use RealInput as input. This input is  normally used for a time series. If just want to give a constant value you should normally use the block Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Constant for that.

From the interaction in OpenModelica after simulation I see that you can give the vector y[i]  values for each component and remains constant. This value propagate to the input u of y_to_x[i] while the initial value of the integrator y_start is zero, of course.

The block RealInput provide you a way to give constant values as input, without involving a source block. From the FMU you reach these as parameters, not as input signal as I understand it.

In FMPy you provide start_values as a dictionary including both parameters and initial states.
Thus you need to replace "input =" with start_values = { 'integrator.y[2]:2000.0} to get the result you seem to want.

PS. The integration routine you do not need to change for this example.
I just generally use CVODE since default in other contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The correct Python code is:

```
fmu_file = 'integrator.fmu'
model_description = fmpy.read_model_description(fmu_file)
dump(fmu_file)

t_start = 0; t_end = 200; t_step = 0.01

outputs = fmpy.simulate_fmu(
    fmu_file,
    start_time = t_start,
    stop_time = t_end,
    output_interval = t_step,
    star_values={'y[1]':1, 'y[2]':1, 'y[3]':1, 'y[4]':1, 'y[5]':1, 'y[6]':1}, 
    output = ('x[1]','x[2]','x[3]','x[4]','x[5]','x[6]'))
```